ROS Noetic Installation requires credentials -Solved
following this guide (https://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Windows) I get to the actual instalation step:
mkdir c:\opt\chocolatey
set ChocolateyInstall=c:\opt\chocolatey
choco source add -n=ros-win -s="https://aka.ms/ros/public" --priority=1
choco upgrade ros-noetic-desktop_full -y --execution-timeout=0

when im promted for credentials:
By upgrading, you accept licenses for the packages. ros-noetic-desktop_full is not installed. Installing... Invalid credentials specified. Please provide credentials for: https://aka.ms/ros/public User name: Password
If I enter nothing I get:
Failed to fetch results from V2 feed at 'https://ros-win.pkgs.visualstudio.com/ros-win/_packaging/public/nuget/v2/Packages()?$filter=(tolower(Id)%20eq%20'ros-noetic-desktop_full')%20and%20IsLatestVersion&semVerLevel=2.0.0' with following message : Der Antwortstatuscode gibt keinen Erfolg an: 401 (Unauthorized).
ros-noetic-desktop_full not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.
 Source(s): 'https://aka.ms/ros/public;https://community.chocolatey.org/api/v2/'
 NOTE: When you specify explicit sources, it overrides default sources.
If the package version is a prerelease and you didn't specify `--pre`,
 the package may not be found.
Please see https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/troubleshooting for more
 assistance.

Anybody knows if this is intentional and where can I get the required credentials?
EDIT: The issue resolved itself, probably an issue with ROS itself that is now fixed

Please format console output and commands as code formatted text
